# In powershell to treat string as raw sting

Tags: powershell, python, cmd.exe, path, escape-characters

I have to go to this `C:\Users\user\Documents\code\dart\learning_dart\bin\string_lerning\` directory in `Powershell`  I can use `cd C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\code\\dart\\learning_dart\\bin\\string_lerning\\` notice `\` has been converted to `\\`.

In python we have [raw string](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-raw-string)  often when we copy path from **explorer** or **file editor** we have `\` in path we use  **raw string** so we don't have to escape `\`.

In `Powershell` can I do something like the raw string so don't have to escape each character because when we copy string form `file explorer` it contains only single `\` it takes time to escape `\` to `\\`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the single or double quote as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3):

> Quotation marks are used to specify a literal string. You can enclose a string in single quotation marks (') or double quotation marks (").
>
> Quotation marks are also used to create a here-string. A here-string is a single-quoted or double-quoted string in which quotation marks are interpreted literally. A here-string can span multiple lines. All the lines in a here-string are interpreted as strings, even though they are not enclosed in quotation marks.

```
cd 'C:\Users\user\Documents\code\dart\learning_dart\bin\string_lerning\'
```

or

```
cd "C:\Users\user\Documents\code\dart\learning_dart\bin\string_lerning\"
```